# How to write a Python terminal application with a fixed input line?

Tags: python, terminal, spyder, curses, ansi-escape

I'm trying to write a terminal application to interact with an Arduino microcontroller via [pyserial](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/). The following features are important:

- Print incoming messages to the command line.
- Allow the user to enter output messages to the serial port. The input should be possible, while new incoming messages are printed.

In principle, this should be possible with [cmd](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html). But I'm struggling with printing incoming messages, when the user started typing.

For simplicity, I wrote the following test script emulating incoming messages every second. Outgoing messages are just echoed back to the command line with the prefix ">":

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from cmd import Cmd
from threading import Thread
import time

class Prompt(Cmd):

    def default(self, inp):

        print('>', inp)

stop = False

def echo():
    
    while not stop:
        
        print(time.time())
        time.sleep(1)

thread = Thread(target=echo)
thread.daemon = True
thread.start()

try:
    Prompt().cmdloop()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    stop = True
    thread.join()
```

In Spyder IDE, the result is just perfect:

[image: Result in Spyder IDE]

But in iterm2 (Mac OS) the output is pretty messed up:

[image: Result in iterm2]

Since I want to use this application from within Visual Studio Code, it should work outside Spyder. **Do you have any idea how to get the same behaviour in iterm2 as in Spyder?**

Things I already considered or tried out:

- Use the [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) library. This solves my problem of printing text to different regions. But I'm loosing endless scrolling, since curses defines its own fullscreen window.
- Move the cursor using [ansi escape sequences](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php). It might be a possible solution, but I'm just not getting it to work. It always destroys the bottom line where the user is typing. I might need to adjust the [scrolling region](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#scrolling-margins), which I still didn't manage to do.
- Use a different interpreter. I already tried Python vs. iPython, without success. It might be a more subtle setting in Spyder's interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! I found a solution: The [Prompt Toolkit 3.0](https://python-prompt-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pages/asking_for_input.html) in combination with [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) lets you handle this very problem using [`patch_stdout`](https://python-prompt-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pages/reference.html#module-prompt_toolkit.patch_stdout), "a context manager that ensures that print statements within it won’t destroy the user interface".

Here is a minimum working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from prompt_toolkit import PromptSession
from prompt_toolkit.patch_stdout import patch_stdout
import asyncio
import time

async def echo():

    while True:
        
        print(time.time())
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def read():

    session = PromptSession()

    while True:
 
        with patch_stdout():
            line = await session.prompt_async("> ")
            print(line.upper())

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(echo())
loop.create_task(read())
loop.run_forever()
```

[image: screencast]

Comment: Note that this came out to be very similar to [this example](https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/python-prompt-toolkit/blob/master/examples/prompts/asyncio-prompt.py) on the prompt-toolkit GitHub page.

Answer (score 0):

It's a while since I was interacting with an Arduino with my Mac.  I used `pyserial` and it was 100% reliable.  key is user `read_until()`. I've included my wrapper class for illustration.  (Also has an emulation mode for when I didn't have a Arduino)

```
import serial # pip install PySerial
from serial.tools import list_ports
import pty, os # for creating virtual serial interface
from serial import Serial
from typing import Optional


class SerialInterface:
    # define constants which control how class works
    FULLEMULATION=0
    SERIALEMULATION=1
    URLEMULATION=2
    FULLSOLUTION=3

    # define private class level variables
    __emulate:int = FULLEMULATION
    __ser:Serial
    __port:str = ""


    def __init__(self, emulate:int=FULLEMULATION, port:str="") -> None:
        self.__buffer:list = []
        self.__emulate = emulate
        self.__port = port

        #self.listports()

        # setup connection to COM/serial port
        # emulation sets up a virtual port,  but this has not been working
        if emulate == self.FULLSOLUTION:
            self.__ser = serial.Serial(port, 9600)
        elif emulate == self.SERIALEMULATION:
            master, slave = pty.openpty()
            serialport = os.ttyname(slave)

            self.__ser = serial.Serial(port=serialport, baudrate=9600, timeout=1)
        elif emulate == self.URLEMULATION:
            self.__ser = serial.serial_for_url("loop://")


    # useful to show COM/serial ports on a computer
    @staticmethod
    def listports() -> list:
        for p in serial.tools.list_ports.comports():
            print(p, p.device)
            serialport = p.device
        return serial.tools.list_ports.comports()

    def read_until(self, expected:bytes=b'\n', size:Optional[int]=None) -> bytes:
        if self.__emulate == self.FULLEMULATION:
            return self.__buffer.pop()
        else:
            return self.__ser.read_until(expected, size)

    # note it is important to have \n on end of every write to allow data to be read item by item
    def write(self, bytes:bytes=b'') -> None:
        if self.__emulate == self.FULLEMULATION:
            self.__buffer.append(bytes)
        else:
            self.__ser.write(bytes)

    def dataAvail(self) -> bool:
        if self.__emulate == self.FULLEMULATION:
            return len(self.__buffer) > 0
        else:
            return self.__ser.inWaiting() > 0

    def close(self) -> None:
        self.__ser.close()

    def mode(self) -> int:
        return self.__emulate
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this might help. Sorry for my possibly misleading question, but reading from Arduino is not my problem. In my minimum example I even generated completely synthetic messages. The question is rather how to display the _result_ of `read_until`, without interfering with the current user input that is not yet submitted.