# Python Console independent area

Tags: python, console

This might sound weird but I am looking for a module or a workaround which can help me achieve a static text input area of the console at the bottom with the part above it ie the rest of the console, being able to have scrolling text without affecting the input area. All ideas are welcomed!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write a Python terminal application with a fixed input line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62988838/how-to-write-a-python-terminal-application-with-a-fixed-input-line)